# Add cell values having particular text

Tags: excel, excel-formula, google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-sheets-query

First, I know that DSUM and SUMIF works with the values in the entire cell. I would like to know if I can add values of cells where **part of the string** contains a particular text.

Let me explain. I use Google Sheets to manage my expenses, and gather data about my financials. I have something like this—

[image]

As you can see, above is a typical example of a day. Each cell has a category, and a description, and below it, the value in the next row. Now is it possible to add values of the cell containing the word "TAXIS"? This way I should be able to get a sum of expenses for a particular category.

I've tried a vast number of expense managers, but none that I am happy with. Finally have decided to go the manual route, and here I am. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use wild card to add part of string. Suppose you data starts from `C2` cell and data goes like your screenshot then you can use following formula.

```
=SUMIF(C2:K2,"*TAXIS*",C3:K3)
```

Obviously you have to customize formula based on your sheet from where data starts and ends.

Comment: First try, it works, brilliant! Thanks a lot, Harun...you saved the day!

Comment: Glad to know it helps you!

Comment: You can formula like `=SUMIF(C2:K2,"*" & B1 &"*",C3:K3)` where criteria category is in `B1` cell.

Comment: Oh, that's interesting! Thanks, I'll keep that in mind.